# Onclick scroll to next div with a specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.mark').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var next = (Number(id) + 1);
  window.scrollTo($('#'+next));
})
```

```css
.mark {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='marker'>
   <div class='mark' id='1'>Mark 1</div>
   <div class='mark' id='2'>Mark 2</div>
   <div class='mark' id='3'>Mark 3</div>
   <div class='mark' id='4'>Mark 4</div>
   <div class='mark' id='5'>Mark 5</div>
</div>
```

Right here, I'm trying to make my window scroll to the next div with an `id` numbered with current `id + 1`.

I've tried `window.scrollTo($('#'+next));`.

But didn't work, then tried `window.scrollTo($('#'+next), 500);`.

But always returns to first `div + 500px`.

What is the proper way to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos)` takes two parameters. The first one is coordinate along x-axis and second is along y-axis. So you can use 0 for first parameter and `$('#'+next).offset().top` for second parameter

```js
$('.mark').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var next = (Number(id) + 1);
  //window.scrollTo(0, $('#'+next).offset().top);
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $('#'+next).offset().top}, 2000);
})
```

```css
.mark {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='marker'>
   <div class='mark' id='1'>Mark 1</div>
   <div class='mark' id='2'>Mark 2</div>
   <div class='mark' id='3'>Mark 3</div>
   <div class='mark' id='4'>Mark 4</div>
   <div class='mark' id='5'>Mark 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change to to select depending on `data-number`? Since i guess it is pretty bad to use numeric `ID`s?

Comment: @AXAI yes it is possible to select elements using data attributes.

Comment: @AXAI animate what?

Comment: @AXAI check now.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something like this which maybe helpfull for you check out.

HTML

```
<div class='marker'>
   <div class='mark' id='1'>Mark 1</div>
   <div class='mark' id='2'>Mark 2</div>
   <div class='mark' id='3'>Mark 3</div>
   <div class='mark' id='4'>Mark 4</div>
   <div class='mark' id='5'>Mark 5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mark {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mark').click(function(){;
    var y = $(this).outerHeight();
    var z =$(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:z+y},800);
  });
});
```

You can check the [**demo here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=24f042029d35013869f89986cf860247)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.mark').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var next = (Number(id) + 1);
  location.href="#"+next;
});
```

```css
.mark {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='marker'>
   <div class='mark' id='1'>Mark 1</div>
   <div class='mark' id='2'>Mark 2</div>
   <div class='mark' id='3'>Mark 3</div>
   <div class='mark' id='4'>Mark 4</div>
   <div class='mark' id='5'>Mark 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `location.href` works only on `ID`s and `Class`es? Just incase i wanted to use `data`

Comment: @AXAI `location.href` works only on `ID`. So, you want to use `data`, you should find another good way to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution when you use `data-number`.

Actually, it's not perfect solution.

But I hope it help you.

```js
$('.mark').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-number');
  var next = (Number(id) + 1);
  window.scrollTo(0, $(`.mark[data-number=${next}]`).offset().top);
});
```

```css
.mark {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='marker'>
   <div class='mark' data-number='1'>Mark 1</div>
   <div class='mark' data-number='2'>Mark 2</div>
   <div class='mark' data-number='3'>Mark 3</div>
   <div class='mark' data-number='4'>Mark 4</div>
   <div class='mark' data-number='5'>Mark 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a perfect solution?

Comment: @AXAI It's just hint or clue to solve. You can make perfect using this.